# ISLR - linear regression, error of coefficients and resample method

Tags: regression, machine-learning

ISLR is the famous book "Introduction to Statistical Learning - with applications in R", used for many people that are studying data science as me.

Reading the 3rd chapter of ISLR, I have a question about error of coefficients.
If I have some training data, if I assume there is a linear model, then the error of the slope and intercept are easily given from the formulas in chapter 3.

So, for example I do an experiment in physics, 100 data ----> b0 + b1 (with errors!) are the best estimating of the real b0 and b1.

But, is it a good model? Why do we use resample method if we have already these errors? Maybe resample method gives me a more accurate model? (errors of coefficient lower or not?). Do we use resample only for prediction and not inference?

Or, to better find a more accurate linear model in the experiment above, should I use CV with k = 10 and not consider errors explained in the chapter 3?

So for example 10 observations for testing, 90 for training, fit, get b0 and b1, and then repeat for ten times and then do an average for the 10 b0 and 10 b1 
found for every test set?

Comment: @RichardHardy he's most likely referring to [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf).

Comment: Re-sampling allows you to obtain some measure of confidence in your estimated parameters. For example, you can use the estimates obtained from CV or Boostrap to compute confidence intervals for b0 and b1 in a non-parametric way. If your estimated parameters show a high variance (or even change sign) then this is an indicator that your model is unstable and will most likely perform poorly on new data.

Comment: So, what do you think I can do with my experiment (my toy model)? 
Experiment: 100 training data, used to find b0 and b1. Error of them using formula of chapter 3.
Or
CV with k = 10, so use 90 data, 10 for testing, find b0 and b1. Repeating for the other times. At the end I 've got 10 b0 and 10 b1, I've got the mean of them and which errors for these coefficients?

What's the best method of them or should I use both?

Comment: They are equivalent in the sense that you are fitting the same model using the same cost function, except that the CV approach lets you estimate an empirical variance of b0 and b1. For linear regression, the variance of the parameters can be obtained from the co-variance matrix (the lm() function in R will provide you with the se estimates). Estimates obtained on the whole data set, i.e. all 100 samples, will be your best guess of these parameters, however you wont know how stable they are without looking at their variance.